# Where does Wine store files?

Tags: wine, winetricks

I have a dotnet 4.5.2 application, which is just a console application that saves some datafeed into a .txt file. The program depends on some .dll files (private data-connectors, I don't have control over them).

I installed dotnet 4.5.2 via winetricks

```
winetricks -q dotnet45 corefonts
```

Now I'm running my application

```
wine ~/datafeed.exe
```

and cannot filgure out there it actually saves my .txt files?

Comment: Everything installed and running with Wine resides in .wine in your Home folder.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Wine's files are stored in `/home/user/.wine/drive_c/` by default.

`.wine` is a hidden folder, so press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> in your home folder to show it.

You can select other folders in most programs by browsing to the correct place on your hard drive.

Comment: Hi, anonymous2. Thanks! I ve seen this folder, but there are no any files. datafeed.exe has no installer, it's just executable that creates .txt files with data in the same directory, where exe lies

Comment: @IlyaCherevkov, is there a save dialog?

Comment: im working via ssh, `wine ~/datafeed.exe` doesn't propose to save anything

Comment: I resolved it, needed to properly install dotnet via GUI. Files are stored in the directory with datafeed.exe itselft btw

Answer (score 8):

The existing answer in incomplete.

Applications running in wine can store data in the locations specified in `~/.wine/dosdevices`.

Those can also be specified graphically. To do so, launch `Configure Wine` from the dash and switch to the tab `Drives`. The rest should-be self-explanatory.

By default, there are 2 "drives" (as Windows calls them): `c:` and `z:`. `c:` by default points to `../drive_c` which at that location is equal to `~/.wine/drive_c`. So if the application running in wine stored its data on drive `c:`, it's in there.

However, drive `z:` points to `/` which is your file system root. This means that by default wine applications can access all files on your system provided wine has the permissions to do so. So (by default) your user permissions.

Anyways, it's likely that the application stored its data on drive `c:` and therefore in `~/.wine/drive_c` but I think the above is worth knowing, especially if you don't find the file you're looking for in `~/.wine/drive_c`.

Answer (score 1):

Files in ubuntu's ~/Documents folder appear under "My Documents" inside wine.

Comment: Most helpul answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do this command in your terminal:

```
winefile
```

It will open a files manager in a window.  Click "C:" to see the Windows directory.

Comment: Some context would be helpful. Many people don't like to run a command with no idea what it does.

Answer (score 0):

If you, like myself, installed an application that needed to install wine, then `.wine` would be found under the snap directory of the application common data.

For the example where I installed `acrordrdc` :

```
~/snap/acrordrdc/common/.wine
```

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + Command + <kbd>G</kbd> `~/.wine/drive_z`

Then you go to the files, etc.