# Trying to in install .exe files

Tags: themes

Installed vine and verified  same but it is not appearing in the  context menu i`m trying to install an .exe file from a usb stick where do the vine files reside as a newby  i need a clue or two

Comment: They are normally found in `/home/username/.wine/dosdevices` or `/home/username/.wine/drive_c`

Comment: Try using PlayOnLinux. It uses Wine, but it hides a lot of the complexity for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does Wine store files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833808/where-does-wine-store-files)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to install a .exe file and find the file system.

Specifying your username is `dobby,` Wine would be located in

```
/home/dobby/.wine
```

and your files would be in

```
/home/dobby/.wine/drive_c
```

or

```
/home/dobby/.wine/dosdevices/c:
```

To install an exe, you can run it using

```
wine /path/to/your/wine.exe
```

or, if it's standalone, you can move it to

```
/home/dobby/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/FolderForExe/wine.exe
```

Edit: TLDR, just run

```
wine nameoffile.exe
```

to use an EXE

Comment: l have the wine folder containing many files but where do l go from there.you say run *wine /path/to/your/wine.exe* or*/home/dobby/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/FolderForExe/wine.exe* sorry don`t know how to do that. Trying to learn this system but very confusing

Comment: @Dobby If the exe is an installer, go to the terminal/command line and run `wine filename.exe`. If it's a standalone, copy it to a new folder: run `mkdir /home/dobby/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/foldername` and `cp file.exe /home/dobby/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/foldername/file.exe`.